# Stopping Excel Macro executution when pressing Esc won't work

Tags: vba, excel, terminate

I'm running excel 2007 on XP.

Is there a way to stop a macro from running during its execution other than pressing escape?  Usually if I think I created an infinate loop or otherwise messed something up I hit escape and it throws an error but the macro stops.

This time (and I've done it before but not this badly), I set up a msgbox for some quick debugging.  Turns out it had to loop about 6000 times, which made means I had to "OK" 6000 message boxes, which took several minutes.  I didn't save before running (another mistake) so I couldn't open task manager to exit.

Is there another way to stop the execution of a macro in case I goof up like this again?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Use <kbd>CRTL</kbd>+<kbd>BREAK</kbd> to suspend execution at any point. You will be put into break mode and can press <kbd>F5</kbd> to continue the execution or <kbd>F8</kbd> to execute the code step-by-step in the visual debugger.

Of course this only works when there is no message box open, so if your VBA code constantly opens message boxes for some reason it will become a little tricky to press the keys at the right moment.

You can even edit most of the code while it is running.

Use `Debug.Print` to print out messages to the [Immediate Window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251339%28v=office.15%29.aspx) in the VBA editor, that's way more convenient than `MsgBox`.

Use [breakpoints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264172%28v=office.15%29.aspx) or the `Stop` keyword to automatically halt execution in interesting areas.

You can use `Debug.Assert` to [halt execution conditionally](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251583%28v=office.15%29.aspx).

Comment: on my Lenovo used Fn B [link](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkPad-11e-Windows-E-and-Edge/E220s-How-to-press-Ctrl-Break/ta-p/560643)

Comment: Excel will not stop until it reaches a point where it looks for key presses. If you have a tight endless loop, it will never stop until you kill excel using task manager, in which case you will lose anything not saved. If you add a DoEvents statement inside your loop it will force Excel to process events like key presses. (It will also slow your code down.)

Answer (score 21):

CTRL + SCR LK (Scroll Lock) worked for me.

Comment: Worked in Access 2010 with message box open

Comment: Notably, this worked for me when I did not have a `break` key on my keyboard.

Comment: This crashed to the blue screen of death on a keyboard with a `break` key, work computer.

Comment: I was stuck because MS Sculpt keyboard does not have a break key and Escape did not help. This works for me in Outlook VBA

Answer (score 12):

Sometimes, the right set of keys (<kbd>Pause</kbd>, <kbd>Break</kbd> or <kbd>ScrLk)</kbd> are not available on the keyboard (mostly happens with laptop users) and pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> 2, 3 or multiple times doesn't halt the macro too.

I got stuck too and eventually found the solution in accessibility feature of Windows after which I tried all the researched options and 3 of them worked for me in 3 different scenarios.

**Step #01**: If your keyboard does not have a specific key, please do not worry and open the 'OnScreen Keyboard' from Windows Utilities by pressing <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>.

**Step #02**: Now, try any of the below option and of them will definitely work depending on your system architecture i.e. OS and Office version

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Pause</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>ScrLk</kbd>
- <kbd>Esc</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd> (Press twice consecutively)

You will be put into break mode using the above key combinations as the macro suspends execution immediately finishing the current task. For eg. if it is pulling the data from web then it will halt immediately before execting any next command but after pulling the data, following which one can press <kbd>F5</kbd> or <kbd>F8</kbd> to continue the debugging.

Comment: I'm afraid none of those work, even with onscreen KB, with Excel 2016.

Answer (score 4):

You can stop a macro by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>break</kbd> but **if you don't have the break key** you could use this [autohotkey](https://autohotkey.com) (open source) code:

> +ESC:: SendInput 
>   {CtrlBreak}
>   return

Pressing <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>Escape</kbd> will be like pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>break</kbd> and thus will stop your macro.

All the glory to [this page](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/73641-stupid-laptop-has-no-break-key/)

Answer (score 3):

I also like to use MsgBox for debugging, and I've run into this same issue more than once.  Now I always add a Cancel button to the popup, and exit the macro if Cancel is pressed.  Example code:

```
    If MsgBox("Debug message", vbOKCancel, "Debugging") = vbCancel Then Exit Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Just Keep pressing `ESC` key. It will stop the VBA. This methods works when you get infinite `MsgBox` s

Answer (score 1):

You can also try pressing the "FN" or function key with the button "Break" or with the button "sys rq" - system request as this - must be pressed together and this stops any running macro

Comment: Does nothing in Excel 2016

Answer (score 1):

I've found that sometimes whem I open a second Excel window and run a macro on that second window, the execution of the first one stops. I don't know why it doesn't work all the time, but you may try.

Answer (score 1):

ESC and CTRL-BREAK did not work for me just now.
But CTRL-ESC worked!?
No idea why, but I thought I would throw it out there in case it helps someone else.
(I had forgotten i = i + 1 in my loop...)

Comment: Thanks.  Note that if you're stepping though a list of numbers, you can consider using something like: `For i = 1 to 10 step 1`.  That would be cleaner and a way of writing less prone to infinite loops!

Comment: Yes, thanks for the reply. I normally do it as you describe. IIRC in this case I was comparing two different lists and iterating conditionally, so a do loop with i = i + 1 in various places seemed the most efficient. Having said that, I'm an engineer not a programmer so I'm sure I often don't use the best coding practices.

Comment: Ctrl-Esc brings up start menu in Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to comment out a line with a MsgBox before executing my macro. Meaning I'd have to click OK over a hundred thousand times. The ESC key was just escaping the message box but not stopping the execution of the macro. Holding the ESC key continuously for a few seconds helped me stop the execution of the code.

Comment: This is how I was able to live with the code I had as-is, but again, there were several thousand message boxes.  It took literally several minutes to get through the execution of macro while I held down the escape/enter key - which was agonizing to say the least. You should keep what the other answers say in mind, because you cannot brute-force your way out of an infinite loop, or a program that never ends.

Answer (score 0):

My laptop did not have Break nor Scr Lock, so I somehow managed to make it work by pressing **Ctrl + Function + Right Shift (to activate 'pause')**.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is completely different and far much better and easy, since usually ESC or ctrl+break and other commands do not work. To prevent the data loss due to forced killing of Excel or Word, I use these steps in MS Windows 10:

1. open the command shell (click on Start button or press Win key on your keyboard, then type ‘cmd’ and select Run as administrator)
2. write: ‘shutdown /h’ (without quotes of course) and press Enter key - the computer goes to hibernation, which has higher priority than running VBA = this will break the macro safely
3. wake up the computer again and log in
4. now, you can see the pop-up prompt to end the macro… no data loss, no program killing

You’re welcome.